# EJS tags giving me SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I have a `views` folder with `campgrounds.ejs`, `landing.ejs`, and a `partials` folder. Inside the partials folder are my `header.ejs` and `footer.ejs` files.

`SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in C:\Users\hawkm\Desktop\YelpCamp\views\Landing.ejs while compiling ejs`

```
<% include partials/header %>

<h1>Landing Page</h1>

<p>Welcome To YelpCamp!</p>

<a href="/campgrounds">View All The Campgrounds</a>

<% include partials/footer %>
```

I'm sure it's something incredibly simple...

Answer (score 0):

Problem was the syntax. This worked...

~<%- include ("partials/header") %>

<%- include ("partials/footer") %>~